# Random item from collection - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a collection with objects in them.

```
Collection { '378570673196367892' => [Object], '37858392' => [Object], '28284' => [Object] }
```

In the object there is a function I want to call, add emoji.

For the first object it's easy. I just use:

```
<Collection>.first().addemoji('abc', 'def')
```

But: I want to take a random object to execute the addemoji thing on.

So it will be

```
<Random selected Object>.addemoji('abc', 'def')
```

Comment: I don't know how to get a random Object from a collection with Objects

Comment: `const keys = Object.keys(yourCollection), len = keys.length, key = keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * len), item = yourCollection[key];`

Comment: ^^ Not working. ^^

Answer (score -1):

```
var allkeys = Object.keys(collection)
var randomObject = collection.get(allKeys[ allKeys.length * Math.random() << 0]);
randomObject.addemoji('abc', 'def');
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Just a sidenote: I have to use `<Collection>.get('378570673196367892')` to get a item.
`<Collection>[index]` does not work.

Comment: No. It returns undefined

Comment: `var allkeys = Object.keys(client.guilds)
var randomObject = client.guilds.get(allkeys[ allkeys.length * Math.random() << 0]);`

Comment: `client.guilds` is my object

Comment: `var allkeys = Object.keys(client.guilds); console.log(allkeys[ allkeys.length * Math.random() << 0]);` Returns undefined

Comment: i have checked it its working on my collections.......there must be a problem in your data? check it

Comment: The type of the object is a `[object Map]` and everything is just fine.

`Collection { '378570673196367892' => [Object], '37858392' => [Object], '28284' => [Object] }`

Comment: Can you add an explanation of your code? the `<< 0` isn't obvious (for me at least)

Comment: its a short hand version of parseInt() or you can say Math.round()